# Xcode valid signing identity not found, managing 2 dev accounts

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

I have a business account/profile that I used for app1. I put out app1 on the market and it is currently online. I then started a personal app2 with another dev account and finished app2 and tried to put it on the market. I got an error that I can only have one distribution certificate in the keychain so I removed my business one and was able to submit my personal app2. So now I am trying to make some changes on app1 but now I am getting a "valid signing identity not found" warning. So I tried re-downloading my distribution certificate and whatnot, tried creating new profiles, nothing is working. In the keychain I can view the certificate and there is no private key associated with it. I've read about everyone else who has encountered the "valid signing identity not found" problem and it seems the common solution is to revoke the certificate and create a new one. Except that I read that if you revoke the current certificate then my app will stop working on all devices & I can't have that happening. Please tell me apple didn't just screw me over (again).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this link, which answers the question: [What, if any "screw it up permanently" situations are there in the App Store certificate/key-pair code signing process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10642989/what-if-any-screw-it-up-permanently-situations-are-there-in-the-app-store-cer)

> A Distribution certificate is used only for submission to iTunes Connect (and Ad Hoc stuff). Once approved, Apple signs the app with a different non-expiring certificate before putting the app in the App store, so the state of the developer's Distribution certificate no longer matters.